# How to do Eclipse style TDD with Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tdd

I just bought a copy of Intellij and I need to generate a unit test stub and put junit on the classpath and set the test to execute with the junit runner. It's trivial to do so in Eclipse.

Every instruction I read looks like this...

1. Create a class to test
2. Add method
3. Create a test source root
4. Create a test class
5. Run test

But I do not want to create any class, or any Method until I have a Test that won't compile.

I want to layout the Class and method stubs first in a test. Once I am satisfied with the API I've expressed in the test I want to auto generate the Class and Method declarations, and then begin with the assertions.

How to do this in Intellij?

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with intellij; it's a TDD problem in general. The usual approach is to write some stubs with bodies like `throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // TODO`, then write tests against those, and then work until those tests pass. But you mention stubbing already; so, what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I think it is a problem with Intellij not supporting a workflow that is considered a best practice by many developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a File Template to add a stub unit test and keep a TTD workflow similar to Eclipses.

1. Rt click the project root in the Project pane. Select New > Edit File Templates...
2. Copy the Java Class Template and overwrite the Name to JUnit and Code to...

   ```
   #if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
   import org.junit.Test;
   #parse("File Header.java")
   public class ${NAME} {
       @Test
       public void test() {
       }
   }
   ```

Now when you right click a package you can add a new JUnit stub by selecting New > Java Class > Kind = JUnit

Comment: not sure why the code section is formatting the way it is sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Create a test folder and add a new test class, for example `WhateverTest.java`

Add a new method that has an `@Test` annotation.

```
@Test
public static void whatever() {
}
```

After you import all the required JUnit dependencies (and the ones you want), you can simply tell intellij to run the tests in the class. I don't think you have to do any special configuration beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA does not support the auto-generation of main classes from test classes. It will auto generate test classes and methods from a main class. So you could do as @yshavit recommends in his comment and create a main class skeleton and then auto generate the test class via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Or as you write your test, keep an interface in sync with it. Then you can auto generate an implementation from the interface.

Otherwise, as I see it, you have three options:

1. Open a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) for auto-generating production classes from test classes
2. Write your own plug-in to do this
3. Ask the author of an existing plug-in, such as the [Enso](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6403?pr=idea) TDD focused plug-in, to add this feature.

Comment: I actually tried duplicating the Java Class file template and added a method stub to make it a junit. However it does not appear in the New dialog, and the Intellij docs offer no solution I can find to make it available.

Comment: See my [post here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5499184#5499184) for info on using a new file template. It is something that needs to be a little better documented :)

Comment: Unfortunately select "From File Templates" is not available for me when I right click my project/src-folder/package and choose New in Intellij 12.1.4.

Comment: Sorry - my bad - that's for non Java templates only (as of 3 or 4 versions ago). For a Java template, select new > "Java Class". In the "Create New Class" dialog, select your template from the "Kind" drop down. You can use inline search when that drop down has focus.